# Spectrum and tower decomposition

Tags: spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to read ["Partitions of Lebesgue space in trajectories defined by ergodic automorphisms" by Belinskaya (1968)](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=faa&paperid=2778&option_lang=eng). In the beginning of the proof of theorem 2.7, the author considers an ergodic automorphism $R$ of a Lebesgue space whose spectrum contains all $2^i$-th roots of unity ($i=1,2,\ldots$), and then he/she claims that for each $i$ there exists a system of sets ${\{D_i^k\}}_{k=1}^{2^i}$ such that $R D_i^k=D_i^{k+1}$ for $k=1, \ldots, 2^i-1$ and $R D_i^{2^i}=D_i^1$. I'm rather a newbie in ergodic theory and I don't know where this claim comes from. I would appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be an ergodic automorphism of a Lebesgue space. Let $\omega$ be a root of unity in the spectrum of $R$, and $n$ be the smallest positive integer such that $\omega^n = 1$.

Let $f$ be a non-zero eigenfunction corresponding to the eigenvalue $\omega$. Then:

$f^n \circ R = (f \circ R)^n = (\omega f)^n = f^n,$

and $f^n$ is an eigenfunction for the eigenvalue $1$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $f^n$ is bounded (you just have to take $f/|f|$ instead whenever $f \neq 0$). Then, since the transformation is ergodic, $f^n$ is constant. Up to multiplication by a constant, we can assume that $f^n \equiv 1$.

Thus $f$ takes its values in the group generated by $\omega$. For all $0 \leq k < n$, let $A_k$ be the set $\{f = \omega^k\}$. This is a partition of the whole space. Moreover, if $x \in A_k$, then $f \circ R (x) = \omega f(x) = \omega \cdot \omega^k = \omega^{k+1}$, so $R (x) \in A_{k+1}$ (with the addition taken modulo $n$), and conversely. Hence, $R A_k = A_{k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks. Very elementary actually. I have to overcome the pychological barriers of the newbie.